# How to enable camera in MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an iOS application with a button to report an issue using SMS/iMessage. I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to present the message composition interface using the following code (Swift 3):

```
if(MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()){

        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        controller.body = "Example Message"
        controller.recipients = ["2345678901"]
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I have also implemented the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate function to dismiss properly. A standard text message / iMessage sends successfully, but the user does not have the option to attach an image. The buttons for camera, iMessage Apps, etc. are there, but they are disabled and cannot be pressed. How can I enable these buttons (camera, specifically) to allow my users to attach images to messages composed with the app?

The Buttons in Question:
[image: The Buttons in Question]

EDIT: 
Thanks Abdelahad for the suggestion. I've modified his response to allow multiple recipients and to include a message body. I also updated it to remove the deprecated `addingPercentEscapes(using: )` method.

Here is a solution using a url to open the Messages app. NOTE: This takes users out of the app.

```
let recipients = "2345678901,3456789012" //Phone Numbers
let messageBody = "This is a test"
let sms: String = "sms://open?addresses=\(recipients)&body=\(messageBody)"
let smsEncoded = sms.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
let url = URL(string: smsEncoded!)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

But still I would like a solution that does not take the user out of the app. Is this possible? Why would the MFMessageComposeViewController show the buttons without enabling them?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm encountering the same issue right now

Comment: No I did not. It seems like it's a bug in the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate

Comment: It is definitely a bug, facing the same issue. The only proper solution right now is to use url.

Comment: It is 2020 and I think this problem still exists.   I have been looking for a solution and thus far, I have found nothing.  My understanding is that the camera button worked until iOS 10 and then it stopped.  We're now up to iOS13 and the non-working button is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use  MFMessageComposeViewController  use  UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)  but  this will takes the user out of the app

```
var phoneToCall: String = "sms: +201016588557"
var phoneToCallEncoded = phoneToCall.addingPercentEscapes(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
var url = URL(string: phoneToCallEncoded)
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Taking users into the Messages app does enable the camera, but I'm looking for a solution that won't take the user out of the app. I also need to be able to pre-fill the message text. Is there a way to do this with the method described?

Comment: you can attach an image , or you need to have  have camera worked

Comment: Ok this solution partially worked: `let phoneToCall: String = "sms://open?addresses=\(recipients)&body=\(text)"
        let phoneToCallEncoded = phoneToCall.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)
        let url = URL(string: phoneToCallEncoded!)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)` but it still takes the user out of the app, which is undesirable.

Comment: yes i checked it and edit my answer that this will take user outside the app